# Longest palindrome in a string and it's length

Tags: c

I have a program that is supposed to go through a string identify possible palindromes, check if it is a palindrome and then return the length from `palindromelength()` or -1 if it is not, and print out the longest palindrome of the string.
The program is compiling but the output is wrong.

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int palindromelength(char *str, int i, int j){
    char *start = str;
    char *end  = str + j;
    while(start < end){
        if(*start != *end)
            return -1;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
    return j-i+1;
}
void ispalindrome(char *str){
    int length = 1, max = 1, start =0, i, j;
    for(i=0; i<= strlen(str) -2; i++){
        for(j= 1; j <= strlen(str)-1; j++){
            if(abs(i-j) > 1){
                length = palindromelength(str, i, j);
                if( length> max){
                    max = length;
                    start = i;
                }
            }
        }   
    }
    if(max > 1){
        printf("Largest palindrome is ");
        for( ; start <= j; start++){
            printf("%c", str[start]);
            start++;
        }
    }
    else
        printf("No palindromes in string.");
}

int main(void) {
    char a[50];
    char *a2;
    printf("Enter a string\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", a);

    int length = strlen(a) + 1;
    a2 = (char*)malloc(length*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(a2, a);
    free (a2);

    char *a3 = &a;
    ispalindrome(a3);

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried the `palindromelength()` separately with a simple string, "aracecar". `palindrimelength(a3, 0, 4)` returns -1 so that is right, `palindromelength(a3, 0, 3)` returns 3 so that is right, but `palindromelength(a3, 1, 7)` returns -1, which is wrong. I double checked my function with other ones on stack overflow and it seems right, what could be the problem?
As for the second function `ispalindrome()` is there a better way I could write that one? It just seems kind of messy right know.

I am a newbie, therefore I may not have yet learned some more advanced/sophisticated variations I could take to solve this.

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger. Please learn it before you write another line of code.  It's an essential skill.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit. I have started to learn on my personal laptop, however  I forgot my laptop out of city and won't have it until the end of the week. For now I'm using the school computers were I do not have access to debuggers, my professor only lets us use syntax highlighting and compilers. So I came here for help.

Comment: Please tell your professor that he/she's wasting everyone's time.  He/she should spend the next few lectures on debugging and allow you use of the necessary tools.

Answer (score 0):

I presume int i is the starting index of the string and int j is the ending index. If that is so, have a closer look at the first line of your palindromelength() function. Could the function ever start from somewhere other than index 0?

As for ways to do the ispalindrome() function, there are many algorithms out there to check whether or not an input is a palindrome, I would suggest having a look around and finding out different methods. If your way works, great! probably the cleanest way is to use recursion although that can take some thinking.